# 'Neither was" usage

Tags: grammar

I really need an explanation regarding the differences between neither was and neither were. For all these while we had been using either or and neither nor.

Comment: In case of "Neither X nor Y", the verb agrees with Y. If Y is singular, the verb is singular. If Y is plural, the verb is plural. See the answer to the linked duplicate question

Comment: Do you have a particular sentence in mind? Something like "Neither was I" perhaps? Please [edit the question](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/226968/edit) to make it as complete as possible before it's closed.